# mysql foreign key does not check for correct values

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, key-value-store

I have 3 tables:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE World_Type ( 
  Name_             varchar (15) NOT NULL,
  Skills            varchar (30),
  Bonus             varchar (30),       
  Penalty           varchar (30),
  Description       varchar (90),
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_)   );

  CREATE TABLE Class (
  Class_name        varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Description       varchar (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (Class_name)  );

CREATE TABLE character_ ( 
  Name_             varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Class             varchar (30),
  World_Type        varchar (15),
  Str               integer     ,
  WS                integer     ,               
  BS                integer     ,
  Fel               integer     ,
  Per               integer     ,
  Int_              integer     ,
  Agi               integer     ,
  WP                integer     ,
  Tough             integer     ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (Name_)           ,
  FOREIGN KEY (Class) REFERENCES Class(Class_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (World_Type) REFERENCES World_Type(Name_)     );

  CREATE TABLE world_class_requirements (
  World_Type        varchar (15) NOT NULL,
  Class_name        varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (World_Type, Class_name),
  FOREIGN KEY (World_Type) REFERENCES World_Type(Name_),
  FOREIGN KEY (Class_Name) REFERENCES Class(Class_name)     );
```

When a person is created in character_, it should check if its possible to have correct combination, and insert if the conditions are correct and make an error if not. However even if i intentionally insert invalid combination of worl_type and class it still is inserted in the character_ table.

the Values in world_class_requirements, are:

```
INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Feral World','Assassin');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Feral World','Guardsman');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Feral World','Imperial Psyker');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Feral World','Scum');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Arbitrator');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Assassin');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Cleric');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Guardsman');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Imperial Psyker');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Scum');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Hive World','Tech-Priest');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Adept');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Arbitrator');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Assassin');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Cleric');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Guardsman');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Imperial Psyker');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Scum');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Imperial World','Tech-Priest');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Adept');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Arbitrator');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Assassin');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Cleric');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Imperial Psyker');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Scum');

INSERT INTO world_class_requirements (World_Type, Class_name) VALUES (
'Void Born','Tech-Priest');
```

so for example the class "Adept" should not be allowed to be from a world_type "Feral World", yet it still accepts it.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: A _minimal_ example would have been helpful ;) - regarding your question: Where is your insert into character_ checked against world_class_requirements? Your keys only prevent you from inserting something into world_class_requirements which is not in class or World_type.

Comment: ahh i see, so i am using the keys directly from character_ to class and world_type and not through world_class_requirements, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `character_` table has no reference to the `world_class_requirements` table.  I think you need to add the following relationship:

```
FOREIGN KEY (World_Type, Class) REFERENCES world_class_requirements(World_Type, Class),
```

Comment: I see yeah, i have added that code and i get the error Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: i can imagen its because in worl_class_requirements, its the combination that is a unique values, becuase right now the Fkey is not unique

Comment: @Santelices . . . Add the condition before you create the tables.  You cannot add the condition if any rows fail.